# segmentation fault while calling functions in nasm assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am trying to call my own functions in nasm, it works 2 times then it give segmentation fault error. I created two functions display1 and display2 which will display "This is message1" and "This is message2" respectively. These functions correctly for the first time but then shows segmentation fault on calling these functions twice.

```
global _start

section .text

display1:
    mov eax, 0x4
    mov ebx, 0x1
    mov ecx, var1
    mov edx, len1
    int 0x80
    ret
display2:
    mov eax, 0x4
    mov ebx, 0x1
    mov ecx, var2
    mov edx, var2
    int 0x80
    ret

_start:
    call display1
    call display2
    call display1
    call display2
    mov eax, 0x1
    mov ebx, 0x5
    int 0x80

section .data

    var1: db "This is message1", 0x0A, 0x00
    len1 equ $-var1
    var2: db "This is message2", 0x0A, 0x00
    len2 equ $-var2
```

```
This is message1
This is message2
.symtab.strtab.shstrtab.text.data�N!�$�'
                                        �
    �U�����"'��,1��6�=���I���P���functions.nasmdisplay1display2var1len1var2len2_start__bss_start_edata_endThis is message1
This is message2
.symtab.strtab.shstrtab.text.data�N!�$�'
                                        �
    �U�����"'��,1��6�=���I���P���functions.nasmdisplay1display2var1len1var2len2_start__bss_start_edata_endSegmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: You get loads of garbage because you used `mov edx, var2` as the length.  Pointers are large integers.  The system call should eventually just return `-EFAULT` though, once you get to an unmapped page after copying some readable data to the given file descriptor.  (Actually they return `2048`, not an error, when they stop from the unmapped page, on Linux 5.0.1).  And then it should return.  EAX=1 / int 0x80 is `sys_exit`

Comment: Can't reproduce, works fine (printing text + garbage and then exiting with status=5) for me on Linux, after assembling with NASM and linking into a 32-bit static executable with `gcc -no-pie -nostdlib -m32` or `ld -melf_i386`.  Use a debugger to single-step.  Maybe also try `strace` to see what happens to the `_exit` system call.

Comment: yeah , got the error it was ```mov edx, len2 ```` instead of ```` mov edx, var2``` thank you @PeterCordes

Comment: Right, but that doesn't explain the segfault.  I can't reproduce that.  That's the strange part.

Comment: May be the length I described using edx register get some undefined value which used some private space of memory which was used by some other process and gave me segfault error.

Comment: No, Linux has virtual memory and protects processes from each other.  Passing a huge length has interesting effects but shouldn't corrupt the program.  And it doesn't on my system.  (On my system, with stdout = the terminal, write returns `2048`.  With `> foo` to a file, it returns `4078`.  With `./2write  >/dev/null`, the driver for that special device doesn't even check the user-space memory for readability so it actually returns `134520850`).  What kernel version are you using?  And binutils version?  And in case it matters, what exact commands are you using to assemble + link your program?

Comment: the os is ubuntu 12.04 and kernel version is 3.13.0-32-generic
command for assembling is ````nasm -f elf32 -o name name.nasm````
command for linking is ````ld -o name name.o````

Comment: Can you check with GDB what instruction segfaults?  I that kernel is so old that bugs / vulnerabilities in it aren't really interesting or worth pursuing, and presumably if any existed they've been fixed by now.  That's a really old system.

Comment: So you have a 32-bit user-space?  Otherwise `ld` with no options would make a 64-bit executable (and complain about a 32-bit `.o` as input).  Is your kernel 64-bit or also obsolete 32-bit?

Comment: Kernel is also 32bit . The instruction ```` int 0x80```` is causing the segmentation fault. the data stored by the the instruction ````mov edx, var2```` was ```` mov edx, $0x80490e2````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations, you've found a kernel bug (in your very old Ubuntu 12.04 / Linux 3.13.0-32-generic 32-bit kernel).

**`mov edx, var2` passes a very large integer (an address) as the size**.  This is why you get garbage after the 2nd message; the `write` system call is reading memory up to somewhere near an unmapped page and then stopping.

On a non-buggy kernel, then `write` returns and execution continues until the `_exit` system call like you'd expect.

> The instruction `int 0x80` is causing the segmentation fault.

IDK whether that's more or less insane than corrupting user-space and leading to a fault later.

It's probably not worth reporting this kernel bug anywhere. Ubuntu 12.04 LTS reached [End of Life in 2017](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2017/03/15/ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin-reaches-end-of-life-on-april-28-2017/).  The bug doesn't exist in modern kernels and was probably either noticed or fixed by accident as part of some other change in the 7 years since that kernel was current.

---

### What happens in non-buggy kernels with write() that eventually reads from unmapped pages

[The `write(2)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) definitely does *not* document the possibility of raising a signal on bad args, only of error codes like `EFAULT`.

I can't reproduce the segfault on Arch Linux with x86-64 Linux kernel 5.0.1; I get the expected garbage written and then `write(2)` returns the number of bytes written before it hit an unmapped page.  Then execution continues until the `_exit(5)` system call and the process exits cleanly with status=5.

I thought `write` might return `-EFAULT` even after writing some bytes when you pass a pointer+size that includes unmapped pages, but that's not the case.  The wording in the man page doesn't mention this specific case, but the wording of how other errors detected part way through writing are handled is consistent with this.  (Normally those errors are from things like disk becoming full, or maybe the other side of the pipe closing.)

> [**`write(2)` Linux man page**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)
>
> Note that a successful write() may transfer fewer than count bytes.  Such partial writes can occur for various  reasons; ...
>   ...
>   In the event of  a
>          partial write, the caller can make another write() call to transfer the remaining bytes.  The subsequent call will either transfer further bytes
>          or may result in an error (e.g., if the disk is now full).

Linux definitely does *not* always transfer all the way to the end of the last mapped page when you do this.  But it's interesting to see what happens for different cases.

It seems that it copies in chunks, and checks readability of each chunk as it goes.  When a chunk would read from an unmapped page, the error is detected and it returns with a partial write.  If you made another call with `address = buf + first_retval`, you'd probably get a `-EFAULT`.  So it's very much like filling up the disk with a partial write and then detecting it by getting `-ENOSPC` when trying to write the rest.

Redirecting output to a file (in `tmpfs`) on x86-64 Linux 5.0.1 I get `write()` sizes of 4078.  `4096-18 = 4078`, and I'm using a recent `ld` (Binutils 2.32) so the `.data` section is 4k-aligned in the executable, and the start of the section is also page-aligned in memory.  So the end of a page is at `var2 + 4096 - len1`.

```
$ strace ./2write > foo
strace: [ Process PID=28961 runs in 32 bit mode. ]
write(1, "This is message1\n\0", 18)    = 18
write(1, "This is message2\n\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 134520850) = 4078
write(1, "This is message1\n\0", 18)    = 18
write(1, "This is message2\n\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 134520850) = 4078
exit(5)                                 = ?
+++ exited with 5 +++
```

vs. writing to the terminal, I get a size of `2048`

vs. writing to `/dev/null`, I get success with write returning `134520850`.  The driver for the `null` special block device doesn't even read the user-space memory, it just returns success from `write` system calls that make it that far.  So nothing ever checks for `-EFAULT`.

Piping the output to `wc`, I got a surprising 18-byte partial-write on the first bad call, and `-EFAULT` on the next.

```
strace ./2write | wc
execve("./2write", ["./2write"], 0x7ffdba771cf0 /* 53 vars */) = 0
strace: [ Process PID=29008 runs in 32 bit mode. ]
write(1, "This is message1\n\0", 18)    = 18
write(1, "This is message2\n\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 134520850) = 18
write(1, "This is message1\n\0", 18)    = 18
write(1, "This is message2\n\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 134520850) = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
exit(5)                                 = ?
+++ exited with 5 +++
      3       9      54
```

On subsequent runs of the program, I got `-EFAULT` right away.  I'm guessing that Linux may have allocated more memory for a pipe buffer after the first call, so then it was able to look far enough ahead to notice the bad address right away, before copying any data.

```
peter@volta:/tmp$ strace ./2write | wc
execve("./2write", ["./2write"], 0x7fff868a41b0 /* 53 vars */) = 0
strace: [ Process PID=29015 runs in 32 bit mode. ]
write(1, "This is message1\n\0", 18)    = 18
write(1, "This is message2\n\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 134520850) = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
write(1, "This is message1\n\0", 18)    = 18
write(1, "This is message2\n\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 134520850) = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
exit(5)                                 = ?
      2       6      36
```